# Ruby on Rails, retrieving API key from secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone help me understand how to retrieve an API key if I'm storing it into **secrets.yml**?

If I have some kind of google API key `'yt_key'`:

**secrets.yml**

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 390257802398523094820 #some key
  yt_key: A423092389042430 #some key

test:
  secret_key_base: 43208947502938530298525#some key
  yt_key: A423092389042430 #some key

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  yt_key: <%= ENV["YT_KEY"] %>
```

I'm just following the examples, this is how I would set it up right?

So if I publish this to production, I would save the `A423092389042430` in heroku and under `YT_KEY`, correct?

But in development, would I do it this way to retrieve the data:

in **/config/application.rb**

```
Yt.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = '<%= ENV["YT_KEY"] %>'
end
```

or should this be in the the class:

```
module Sample
  class Application < Rails::Application

    Yt.configure do |config|
      config.api_key = '<%= ENV["YT_KEY"] %>'
    end

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

Or did I set up the configure wrong?

Comment: Sounds like `Yt.configure` should be in `initializers/yt.rb`. And there is no need to put `<%= %>` in a ruby file.

Answer (score 5):

`ENV["YT_KEY"]` references the 'YT_KEY' [environment variable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=environment%20variable) which you'll have to set with a [Heroku config variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

In your app, you can access your secrets like this:

```
Rails.application.secrets.key_name
```

Since you're storing the 'YT_KEY' as an environment variable in production only, you should configure Yt like so:

(You can do this in a initializer file located at `app/initializers/yt.rb`)

```
Yt.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.yt_key
end
```

That way, the correct key will be set in each environment.

It's good practice to use different keys for each environment, so should get another key for your production environment. Also, you should avoid storing secret production environment keys in the code. That's why it's common to use ENV variables for production keys.

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way, we are doing this way since a long time and working very well for us and this is a good convention as well.

secrets.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 390257802398523094820 #some key
  yt_key: A423092389042430 #some key

test:
  secret_key_base: 43208947502938530298525#some key
  yt_key: A423092389042430 #some key

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  yt_key: <%= ENV["YT_KEY"] %>
```

Add these line to your `application.rb` file

```
 config_files = ['secrets.yml']

    config_files.each do |file_name|
      file_path = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', file_name)
      config_keys = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML::load(IO.read(file_path)))[Rails.env]
      config_keys.each do |k,v|
        ENV[k.upcase] ||= v
      end
    end
```

and now you can access `yt_key` this way `ENV["YT_KEY"]` or any other key you add like `some_key` to `ENV["SOME_KEY"]`.

It's often recommended to not put your custom keys in `secret.yml` instead make another file like `app_keys.yml` and put all keys there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro).

Once installed, you'll have a `config/application.yml` file. Inside it you can store your api keys etc.:

```
SENDGRID_USERNAME: a-name
SENDGRID_PASSWORD: password
```

Now, anywhere in your `.rb` files, you can reference it using vars:

```
# Noticed how I keep my vars uppercase throughout.

ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"]
ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]

# Production vars go below the `production` line

production:
  ENV["MY_PRODUCTION_VAR"]
```

If using those `env` keys inside your `html.erb` then you'll need to wrap it with `<%= ... %>`